# Generate plot of conditional mean of y, given continuous x in R / ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a line plot in  R that shows the conditional mean of y for a given range of x, where x is uniformly distributed between 0 and 1. I would like to be able to specify the bin width to be 1% point wide, so my line would have 100 data points. I would particularly like to know how this can be done in ggplot2.

```
x=runif(10000,0,1)
y=rnorm(10000,50,10)
plot(x,y)
```

Creating a scatter plot generates 10000 points, which makes interpretation hard.

Comment: do you need to pull out the mean value at each of the 100 points or are you just looking to plot a line on your ggplot?

Comment: Need to plot the mean value for each bin. So output will be a simple line plot (no scatter points)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe using `ggplot2::stat_smooth()` with n = 100 (for evaluating at 100 evenly spread points) is enough for you here:

```
data <- data.frame(x,y)
ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(n = 100) # you can change the "method" argument for different fits see ?stat_smooth
```

[image]